# Airflow dag executing middle tasks after completing stop_dag task, how to stop other tasks want to dependency even though parent task did not ran

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

[image: Flow screenshot]

Here is the image after stop execution step, highlighted steps are running without any dependency. please help to stop other task after stop_dag task run completed.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure I understand you correctly but you want that the red marked tasks don't run in case `stop_dag` is successful? This can be accomplished using [trigger rules](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dags.html#concepts-trigger-rules) and one extra task.

I tried to recreate your setup with EmptyOperators:

[image: Recreation of your setup]

Then I add a set of dependencies and an additional task that fails if stop_task is successful due to the trigger rule `all_failed`:

```
fail_if_stop_successful = EmptyOperator(
    task_id="fail_if_stop_successful",
    trigger_rule="all_failed"
)
stop_task >> fail_if_stop_successful >> [t3_1, t3_2, t3_3]
```

This creates the following pattern:

[image: stop_task stops t3 tasks if successful]

Full DAG:

```py
from airflow.decorators import dag
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from pendulum import datetime

@dag(
    start_date=datetime(2023,1,1),
    schedule=None,
    catchup=False
)
def test_dag():

    start = EmptyOperator(task_id="start")

    t1 = EmptyOperator(task_id="t1")

    stop_task = EmptyOperator(task_id="stop_task")
    
    t2_1 = EmptyOperator(task_id="t2_1")
    t2_2 = EmptyOperator(task_id="t2_2")
    t2_3 = EmptyOperator(task_id="t2_3")

    t3_1 = EmptyOperator(task_id="t3_1")
    t3_2 = EmptyOperator(task_id="t3_2")
    t3_3 = EmptyOperator(task_id="t3_3")

    t4 = EmptyOperator(task_id="t4")

    end = EmptyOperator(task_id="end")

    # rebuilding the dependencies from your drawing 
    start >> t1 >> [t2_1, t2_2, t2_3]
    start >> stop_task
    t2_1 >> t3_1
    t2_2 >> t3_2
    t2_3 >> t3_3
    [t3_1, t3_2, t3_3] >> t4 >> end

    # making a successful run of stop_task stop t3_1, t3_2, t3_3
    fail_if_stop_successful = EmptyOperator(
        task_id="fail_if_stop_successful", trigger_rule="all_failed"
        )

    stop_task >> fail_if_stop_successful >> [t3_1, t3_2, t3_3]

test_dag()
```